# A neo4j docker service is not starting up

Tags: docker, neo4j

The following is my yaml file for a neo4j docker service:

```
version: "2"
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.2.0
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4js
    env_file:
      - ./test-neo4j.env
    cap_add:
      - SYS_RESOURCE
    expose:
      - 7474
      - 7687
      - 1337
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ../docker-neo4j/test-conf:/conf
      - ../docker-neo4j/data:/data
```

I have the default **[neo4j.conf](https://pastebin.com/Cv9NrmWw)** file inside the **test-conf** directory. The graph is up and running if I don't add the **../docker-neo4j/test-conf:/conf** line to my volumes. If I add that particular line, then the graph is not starting up. And I get the following error:

```
neo4j_1  | Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool
neo4j_1  | Active database: graph.db
neo4j_1  | Directories in use:
neo4j_1  |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j_1  |   config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
neo4j_1  |   logs:         /var/log/neo4j
neo4j_1  |   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
neo4j_1  |   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
neo4j_1  |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j_1  |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j_1  |   run:          /var/run/neo4j
neo4j_1  | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j_1  | Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint
dockerneo4jtest_neo4j_1 exited with code 1
```

I am tierd of googling. I couldn't find appropriate results to resolve this neo4j-docker issue. Is there a work around that can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue with the config you posted [here](https://pastebin.com/Cv9NrmWw).

To solve it simply comment or remove the following line in your config:

```
#dbms.directories.lib=/usr/share/neo4j/lib
```

The directory `/usr/share/neo4j/lib` doesn't exist on the container. The default value for that parameter is `lib` ([link to docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.lib)). You can also set it to `/var/lib/neo4j/lib`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ramvignesh post your neo4j config from ../docker-neo4j/test-conf folder so I can try it locally.